# Issue with GET variables of parent window in iframe

Tags: php, iframe, get

I have a parent window with the URL: `http://example.com?val=test`

In the iframe of that page, I need to get `val` to append to a link.

Currently I'm doing this in the iframe:

```
<?php
$val = $_GET['val'];
?>
<a href ="http://example.com/link.html?val=<?php echo $val ?>">Link</a>
```

The output contains extra `/` and `'` like this:
`http://example.com/link.html?val=\'test\'`

Is there a way to do this properly?

Comment: It doesn't happen to me... maybe try `stripslashes($val)`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$val = trim(stripslashes($_GET['val']),"'");
```

Comment: Thanks, that got rid of the slashes, but the `'` is still at the beginning and end of the value. Just a note, I think you forgot the closing `)` for others reading.

Comment: thanks, sorry about the missing ).  You could try wrapping that in the trim function and trimming the end quote.  I edited my answer to show that.

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing the pain of PHP's magic quotes. You should either turn them off (prefered) or strip the slashes. See http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php for details.

To disable them completely, put this in your php.ini file

```
; Magic quotes for incoming GET/POST/Cookie data.
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

To remove them from $_GET variables, use stripslashes.

```
<?php
// from http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php#91585
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    function stripslashes_gpc(&$value)
    {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
    array_walk_recursive($_GET, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_COOKIE, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_REQUEST, 'stripslashes_gpc');
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Like the answer below, it got rid of the slashes. For some reason the Get still shows a `'` like: `link.html?val='test'`

Comment: Are the quotes in the original URL? `http://example.com?val=test` should not have quotes around the value. Are you sure the URL does not have the quotes `http://example.com?val='test'`?

Comment: It's literally `val=<?php echo $val?>` so not sure why that is happening. Must be something in another included javascript causing that.